# Displayed GitHub Action name doesn't match name in workflow file

Tags: github-actions

We have a workflow that runs whenever a tag with a specific format is pushed to the main repository. Originally, the displayed name is consistent with the `name:` entry at the beginning of the workflow file, but this is no longer the case.

[image]

Before this change, we had a separate repository with a `cron` workflow that ran a python script to push the tag to the main repository, which triggers the workflow there.

We recently moved to using a workflow from the main repository to push the tag, and this is when the different workflow display name changed. There are some differences between the two triggering workflows. The old trigger ran a python script which presumably pushed the tags "from" the script. The new trigger explicitly calls `git push --tags` from the workflow file itself.

I believe the move to the new trigger is why the display name is changed, but I cannot be certain.